# Unusual small bright ring in storm cloud

Tags: atmospheric-optics

[image]I was taking photos of a storm moving through the area, Southwest of Fort Worth, Texas and caught this image in one of the series. The photography is a hobby. I was using my IPhone 6. I researched meteorological optical phenomena, rings, circles, halos, compared pictures I found and did not find anything similar. 6:45 in the evening. The angle of the phone was probably 60-70*;SSE sky with sun beginning to set in the West and the moon is visible low in the photo. Thanks.

Comment: A key question is did you see it visually as well at the time?  If not, there's a high chance it's a digital artifact?

Comment: Could be last rays of the setting sun shining over the cloud next to this one, illuminating only this small part of this cloud.

Comment: You could try asking https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=artefact. Images from there: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:photo.stackexchange.com+artefact&hs=JnK&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Comment: Sorry, busy week so I was unable to follow up on the comments. The bright spot was visible and one of the reasons I took this particular shot. It was not clearly discernible as a ring. I went back and downloaded the series of pictures onto my computer to view from a larger source and did not find anything similar in the series. I could not discern any pixelation in the image either. It could be a artifact, but seems not to follow the usual form from the sources I’ve seen on limited reference. I’ll repost in the photo/stack/artifact when I get time.